# The differences of move and la in MIPS?

Tags: mips, operator-keyword

I'm a beginner of the MIPS. In my opinion, in MIPS move means transfer the value of a register to another, la means transfer the address of a register to another. But the result of the code really confused me.

```
li $v0,8 #to get a string
la $a0,($v0)
move $t0,$v0
```

I use mars to see the value in the registers. Value in $a0 and $t0 are same 8. What's the problem?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: Note that _"la means transfer the address of a register to another"_ isn't exactly true. I'd argue that the more common use-case for `la` is something like `la $reg, some_label`, but some assemblers may support `la reg1, ($reg2)` as well (which would be identical to `move $reg1, reg2`).

Comment: I think in this case  a0's value will be v0's address. But actually a0's value is v0's value. That's the problem. So la doesn't mean transfer the address of a register to  another. It means we treat the value in the register as a address so that it is the same as the key word move? So the register doesn't have real address? Sorry I'm a beginner so these basic questions really confused me.

Comment: _"a0's value will be v0's address"_. Registers don't have addresses, at least none that are accessible to you as a programmer. `la $a0, ($t0)` is just a different way of expressing `move $a0, $t0` (which itself is just syntactic sugar for something like `or $a0, $t0, $zero`, since both `la` and `move` are _pseudo-instructions_).

Answer (score 0):

`la` is intended for a scenario like this:

```
main:
   la $t0, my_array
   lbu $t1,0($t0) ;loads the 2 in my_array into $t1
loop_forever:
   j loop_forever ;halt the cpu

my_array:
.byte 2,4,6,8
```

Essentially, `la` is a convenience tool. In the actual compiled binary, labels do not exist. Instead, you have a distance (measured in bytes) between the location in your code of the `la` instruction and the byte directly after your label (in this case, the location of the `2` in `byte 2,4,6,8`). To better visualize this, we can have the same code with no labels, but using comments to note the offsets.

```
la $t0, 0xC        ;address 0x0
lbu $t1,0($t0)     ;address 0x4
j 0x8              ;address 0x8
.byte 2,4,6,8      ;address 0xC
```

Above, we did `la $t0, 0xC` because the `.byte 2,4,6,8`  was located starting at address `0x0000000C`. If assemblers didn't have the luxury of labels, we'd have to manually count how many bytes are between `la $t0, my_array` and the `2` we're trying to load. And we'd have to recalculate it *every time we made any changes to our source code!* Which, to put it very mildly, is not fun. This is what the assembler does for us every time we have a `la`, `j`, or `jal` in our source code.

`move $t0, $v0`, on the other hand, is just another way to write `addi $t0, $v0, $zero` (or `andi $t0, $v0, $v0` depending on the assembler's preference.)

EDIT: Technically, `la` is a pseudo-instruction that assembles to two instructions but for simplicity's sake I showed it as one instruction even though this is factually inaccurate.